# Intelligent averaging of time series data with python

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, astropy

I have the following (time-series) data:

```
t = [5.13,   5.27,   5.40,   5.46,  190.99, 191.13, 191.267, 368.70, 368.83,  368.90, 368.93]
y = [17.17, 17.18, 17.014, 17.104,  16.981,  16.96,   16.85,  17.27, 17.66,   17.76, 18.01]
```

so, groups of data in short (time) intervals then separated cleanly by a long time gap.

I'm looking for a simple method that will intelligently average these together; sort of a 'Bayesian blocks' but for non-histogram data.

One could do a simple moving average, or numpy convolution, but I'm looking for something a bit smarter that will generalize to larger, similar, but not identical  datasets.

Comment: The return of t_prime=[5.315, 191.129, 368.84], y_prime=[17.117, 16.930, 17.660] is the first-order result I'd be after, but with the option to include weighted data in more sophisticated analyses.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with Pandas.  First, construct a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t,'y':y})
```

Then label the groups according to a time threshold:

```
groups = (df.t.diff() > 10).cumsum()
```

That gives you `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, because `cumsum()` on a boolean array increments wherever the input is true.

Finally, use `groupby()`:

```
df.groupby(groups).mean()
```

It gives you:

```
         t          y
t                    
0    5.315  17.117000
1  191.129  16.930333
2  368.840  17.675000
```

If you need plain NumPy arrays at the end, just tack on `.t.values` and `.y.values`.

If you don't know a priori what time threshold to use, I'm sure you can come up with some heuristic, perhaps involving simple statistics on `df.t` and `df.t.diff()`.

Comment: Yeah, (a) I was trying to avoid having to 'guess' t time threshold, and (b) don't think this works if the time data aren't in order

Comment: @npross: I think (a) you'll have to build the heuristic yourself using your real data, and (b) you can either sort the data by `t` or "virtually" sort it using `argsort()`.  Note that your example `t` data is sorted, so it was reasonable to assume it would be sorted in reality.